# How to justify guns being advanced earlier

Tags: technology, warfare, weapons, history, guns

In my world's history, firearms were developed in their medieval period, much like our world. However, they have things like culverins in the 1300s, and handgonnes that work better than in real history. How would a different world be able to have some sort of advanced tech in a past period or era?

Comment: How early and what culture? Chinese culture seems to have discovered gunpowder in the 1st century, but what are you counting as a "gun"? As long-range explosives/incendiaries seem to have been around since the Song dynasty - 9th century. Bronze casting seems to have been around since 4000 BC at least making culverins/cannons possible. I'm not sure what you're asking, can you clarify?

Comment: In these terms, a gun is a weapon with a round metal tube connected to a wooden piece that fires a round, and is hand-held. Note: This is just for the requirements of my world, not trying to be offensive or anything.

Comment: What's wrong with saying "this technology was invented earlier"?

Comment: The two major obstacles are metallurgy and machining. These will have other implications beyond firearms... are you willing to accept those?

Answer (score 8):

**Byzantine gun tech**

[Secrecy, Technology, and War: Greek Fire and the Defense of Byzantium, 678-1204](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3106585?seq=1)

> The question is secrecy. At the heart of the Greek  fire story is the
> legend that this ultimate weapon was also the  ultimate state
> secret--closely kept for 500 years and finally lost even to the
> keepers.

In your timeline, the keepers of Greek Fire modified their explosive incendiary projectors - starting with the explosively pressurized sprays that allowed the documented historical uses, then to throw grenades, then small solid projectiles.  The technologic trajectory is different from the one leading to cannons which were huge catapult equivalents used as siege weapons.  Small caliber guns were made of bronze wrapped with iron wire.  By the period of your story in 1300 guns have been in use for nearly 500 years and pistols for 250.

---

I do not want to get into a scholarly discussion as to exactly what Greek Fire was made of, or how the projectors worked.  Or at least not in the context of this question! There is a long and respectable scholarly argument that explosives and even gunpowder may have played a role and so for a fiction it is reasonable to accept that premise.

Answer (score 5):

### Better steel, lots of good deposits of sodium/potassium nitrate, alchemical discovery of guncotton

Gun technology was hamstrung by these factors for quite some time. Lack of good steel (or the ability to cast cannons out of it) has obvious implications and IIRC hindered the Chinese a lot.

Lack of good nitrate deposits was a big deal. Various nations had to supplement natural supplies with alchemical methods, most of which involved large quantities of shit; Charles I infuriated many people by sending his night soil men to dig up buried poo in / next to peoples houses. The Spanish found huge deposits of sodium nitrate in Chile and control of it was a big deal. Some giant deposits of NaNO3 (or even better, KNO3) will certainly promote gun use and thus development in your world.

Many modern explosives are all made in a similar way: Add anhydrous sulphuric acid to nitric acid and add an oxidisable organic compound or naterial. This is how we make guncotton, nitroglycerine, and TNT. Discovering guncotton earlier will make guns better.

There are various social conditions that can promote gun usage (Europe's feuding states with barons in castles was perfect for moving people towards cannons), but I'll leave others to opine on these, as well as all the gunsmithing stuff which is probably even more important than the chemistry I've outlined.

Comment: Machine tools!!

Answer (score 3):

**Things that need simply someone with a bright idea:**

- [Socket bayonets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet#Socket_bayonets) replacing plug bayonets, soon after plug bayonets replaced pike-and-shot formations. An unshaken pike block still beats musketeers at close range, but it becomes a specialist unit.
- [Paper cartridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_cartridge) with pre-measured powder and ready wadding, replacing powder horns and bullet pouches.
- Slightly under-caliber [Minie bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini%C3%A9_ball) to simplify the ramming. This also allows standard calibers for an army rather than every gunner pouring lead balls himself.
- Iron rods.
- [Matchlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchlock) replacing [cannon locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(firearm)#Hand_cannon).
- [Corned powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpowder#Corning) rather than [serpentine powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpowder#Serpentine).

**Things that won't happen because they need better technology:**

- Rifling.
- Flintlocks and especially wheellocks. They need good springs.
- Caplocks. They need chemistry.
- Smokeless powder. Also chemistry.
- Interchangeable repair parts. Those need industrial methods and precision tools.

Comment: Where does breechloading fall here? Is breech loading even an advantage without rifling and cartridges?

Comment: @DKNguyen, under "precision tools" ...

Answer (score 2):

### With war comes innovation

My suggestion is that in your world. A world war happens early as well.

Empires have conjoined into about 5 major powerhouses. and allies have been formed. Minor wars lead up to this point in conflict where there are two major sides, lets call them the Allegiance and the Justerians.

The Allegiance worked more on the theoretical side, utilizing what they know about flammable materials, and made an unfortunate accidental discovery through a freak accident in the lab.

In a tube, they placed an iron ball on top of the most recent material they manufactured from [dried urine on haystacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWlpyl9bYW0), Their most recent way of testing the efficiency of a combustible material is to have the iron ball on top of of material in a tube. Then one member of the scientific group observes the ball and writes down how far the ball moves upward in the tube when the material is lit on fire.

[image]

The newest material is so combustible, it flies out of the tube and killed the scientist looking down into it. The other scientist, shocked, immediately report the results to their captain. The captain realizes that this could become a more efficient method in weaponry and commissions a new task to them. Make it so i can carry the test tube and fire it easily.

A couple of years in toying with new materials and with the solution creates the worlds first firearm. Forcing the Justerians to match the Allegiances recent advance through the works of reverse engineering. Starting the arms race early.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the Chinese do it. now, I'm not a Chinese history major, I'm simply looking to throw my 2 cents into the matter. China invented gunpowder in the 9th century and made guns featuring gunpowder in the 10th. though this system would fundamentally change the entire world, especially considering how distant this is from the 2000s, that's fun, run with the change :). you could possibly keep the previous confusious system in Korea, with an emperor that endorsed gunpowder as military-grade material, this would spread weaponized gunpowder all over Korea and soon after japan, as well as the deposition of native tribes in the southern plains of china, this is a recipe for a European style form of Asia, surprisingly, I'd assume the north of Asia aka china, japan and Korea would be like the modern east in our world, and the southern parts like modern-day Burma, Malaysia, and Indonesia would be like the modern west, this could transform guns alongside boats considering the geography of southern Asia, the diseases of rice fields also plays into the idea of guns over melee. this could change the world in ways we couldn't dream of, possibly japan could be like the UK in our world, maybe we would see a Japanese America, japan would also be very different from our japan, especially considering if they had a Chinese invasion or two. This gives guns another sector to develope in, like how katanas and longswords developed. i dont believe the guns would merge until later in the centuries, neither side could overpower the other and both sides would still believe "our part of the world is better" until a great war or two in the following decades.